# Sticky footer not sticky on each page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a sticky footer on my site. But all the time when I fix it for one page, it breaks on the other page.

As if the current situation on the [homepage](http://bitly.com/1Bl3Jd6) there is a white space below the footer. But on [this](http://bitly.com/ZdNOQj) page it is looking fine.

I am looking for sollution to work on all pages.

Thanks very much.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but the footer is not sticky on either page. I have a large monitor and there is a large white space below the footer on both.

Comment: @mtaube hmm your'e right. Looking for a proper solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The footer is not sticky on either page.

Follow the instructions here to create a sticky footer: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

I have used this pattern on multiple sites and it works great.

Comment: What's the difference between  <div class="footer"> and the <footer> tag?

Comment: @sanders the <footer> tag is HTML5, whereas <div> is used for footers in HTML4. It is best to use HTML5 because the tags are more 'semantic'. These days these elements are safe to use except IE8. See information http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp and http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic

Comment: Tnx. Hmmm a pain that this does not work out of the box with Bootstrap. Because I am using bootstrap framework

Comment: @sanders I use Bootstrap often as well. You can see the sticky footer implemented with Bootstrap here: https://www.garrettleight.com/customer/account/create/

Answer (score 1):

Simple sticky footer guide here!

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Have fun

( Sorry I know this is more a commentaire then a answer but I can't post commentaire yet! )

Answer (score -1):

You need to position that element as `fixed`. Then set `bottom: 0`, also since it looks like it spans across the window, set `left: 0` and `right: 0`. Also, might need to up the z-index value.

Comment: He is not looking for a fixed footer, as that would cover any content that is below the browser edge.